# android java.lang.NullPointerException on http request

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So I am getting this error and I have looked around for awhile and everything points to something being NULL. I am trying to add a auto sms backup feature to my app and every time I run the http connection from my service I get this error and nothing back ups. The only thing I can see that would matter if null or not would be the http URL. But I know that works correctly cause before I set it to a service you could back it up manually. Is there a way to check to see what is causing this error? Find the null?

```
public class SMSBackup extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{       
        @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() 
       {
           super.onPreExecute();   
           Log.i("Info:", "Backing Up");
       }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
         }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {                       
        try
           {                       
                Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriReceive, null, null, null,null);
              // String sms = "";

               while (cur.moveToNext()) 
               {
                   int index_id = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");            // NUMBER LIST OF TEXT IN ORDER
                   int index_Address = cur.getColumnIndex("address");   // NUMBER THAT WAS TEXTED
                   int index_Person = cur.getColumnIndex("person");     // NAME OF CONTACT
                   int index_Body = cur.getColumnIndex("body");         // MESSAGE
                   int index_Date = cur.getColumnIndex("date");         // DATE
                   int index_Type = cur.getColumnIndex("type");         // SENT OR RECEIVED (1 RECEIVED, 2 SENT)
                   int thread_Id = cur.getColumnIndex("thread_id");     // CURRENT TEXT MESSAGE

                    int_id = cur.getInt(index_id);
                    strAddress = cur.getString(index_Address);  
                    intPerson = cur.getString(index_Person);  
                    strbody = cur.getString(index_Body);  
                    longDate = cur.getLong(index_Date);  
                    int_Type = cur.getInt(index_Type);  
                    threadId = cur.getInt(thread_Id);

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new
            HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/index.php");

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_id", Integer.toString(int_id)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_type", Integer.toString(int_Type)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_thread_number", Integer.toString(threadId)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_number", strAddress));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_name", intPerson));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_message", strbody));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            //Log.e("Server Response: ", " " + response);
               }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            //error.setText("Connection error");
           }
            return null;
       }
    }
```

logcat:

```
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at com.trackit.Active$SMSBackup.doInBackground(Active.java:78)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at com.trackit.Active$SMSBackup.doInBackground(Active.java:1)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-28 04:58:23.028: W/System.err(31785):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Where is the error? Post your stack trace please.

Comment: There is no LogCat error.. I get it from Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString()); Which post the java.lang.nullpointerexception.

Comment: catch your error and print via e.printstacktrace() and put it here, apparently seems that error is in getContentResolver() without context. Try that

Comment: Updated with the e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
```

Looks like your asynctask is an inner class of an activity and you have incorrectly instantiated the activity class with `new`. Never instantiate activities with `new`. They won't be set up for `Context` use for starters.

Instead, first remove `extends Activity` or the like from classes you instantiate with `new`. (If you really need to instantiate an activity, use an `Intent`.)

Then pass in a `Context` as an argument where it's needed, for example

```
Context mContext;

// constructor
public SMSBackup(Context ctx) {
    mContext = ctx;
}

// then...
mContext.getContentResolver(...)

// instantiate as in a framework-instantiated activity (a valid Context)
new SMSBackup(this);
```

Comment: Currently I am using Active active = new Active(); active.run_now(); from another .java .. So unsure how I pass Context to it? Can you give me an example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this was a great and quick answer. Thanks for the example as well. Helped me a lot.